# Azure API Management + Service Bus topic : Error 40104: Invalid authorization token audience

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-api-management, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to publish push messages to an Azure Service Bus Topic through Azure API Management. I can do that alright with SAS authentication, but now I would like to rely on a Managed Service Identity.

I am able to retrieve an OAuth token with this policy :

```
<authentication-managed-identity resource="https://my-namespace.windows.net/" output-token-variable-name="sb-msi-access-token" ignore-error="false" />
```

But when I push the message to the topic (on https://my-namespace.servicebus.windows.net/mytopic/messages), I get a frustrating **40104: Invalid authorization token audience**.

If I try and request a token for the following ressource : https://my-namespace.servicebus.windows.net/my-topic
or even https://my-namespace.servicebus.windows.net/my-topic/messages, I get the following error :

**The resource principal named https://my-namespace.servicebus.windows.net/orders was not found in the tenant**

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: This error also comes when SAS token is created from a different topic or queue than the one being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found what the problem was : I was too quick reading the documentation, and it appears I was specifying the wrong ressource.

In the end, the specified resource must be **https://servicebus.azure.net**, whatever the service bus namespace or the queue / topic :

```
<authentication-managed-identity resource="https://servicebus.azure.net/" output-token-variable-name="sb-msi-access-token" ignore-error="false" />
```